# Looping with promise bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Is there any way to loop the promise by number like

```
Promise.map(5, function(i){})
```

So the above code will loop 5 times

Right now promise expects an array

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Right now, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: instead of passing array to the promise.map i want to pass 5 as value so that i can iterate it 5 times

Comment: How is this even related to promises? Why don't you use a loop? `for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { }`

Comment: because i want to perform some promises within so i wont know when the loop is finished if i use for loop

Comment: One option: `Promise.map(Array.from(Array(5).keys()), function(i){})`. Basically, you're looking for the `range()` function, or at least a way to emulate it.

Comment: Array(5) made it work. I think promise does not have a function in which i can directly pass integer. but thanks. i can accept that as a answer if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option: `Promise.map(Array.from(Array(5).keys()), function(i){})`

Basically, you're looking for the `range()` method, or at least a way to emulate it. If the Promise implementation you're using doesn't offer a `range()` method (and the most excellent bluebird Promise library doesn't), the code I provided above is a pretty concise way of emulating it.

Other options:

```
//If you're using lodash, underscore or any other library with a .range() method
Promise.map(_.range(5), function(i){})

//Or write your own reusable range() function
// ES6 arrow function syntax
var myRange = i => Array.from(Array(i).keys())
// or classic function syntax
var myRange = function (i) {return Array.from(Array(i).keys())}

Promise.map(myRange(5), function(i){})
```